# create two level subdomain using directadmin control panel

Tags: directadmin

I'm setting up my website and I need two level subdomain like `sub.sub.domain.com`

I have try this in `manage subdomain` part but it creates a folder like `sub.sub`

can anyone help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

one way to this simply is that :

- first create an account in directadmin with a subdomain as main domain of account for example : `sub1.domain.com`
- then go to your subdomain management in directadmin for account `sub1.domain.com` and create a subdomain there like `sub2`
- at the end you have `sub2.sub1.domain.com` in directadmin.